# Pass tap events to superview but handle long press

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to pass tap events to the superview but handle longpress events. I've added LongPressGestureRecognizer to the top view but the tap events aren't passed to the superview. I tried multiple approaches:

- Overriding hitTest doesn't work since the longpress gesture recognizer handler doesn't get called
- isUserInteractionEnabled - same as above
- Overriding touchesBegan/Ended and calling them manually on the superview doesn't trigger the tap event

Comment: I think you can use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool

Answer (score 1):

Handing complex tap interactions can be hard, and mixing different approaches can make it much much harder.

Generally, the best way to handle it is to have a single view that has multiple gesture recognisers on them.  Implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` and `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRequireFailureOf:)` to handle conflicts. When a touch event is recognised it can delegate the action to whatever other object needs to deal with it.  Having different views all trying to deal with touches at the same time is not a good way to deal with the problem.  Gestures are **dependent** on other gestures and cannot all be handled **independently** by different views.

Comment: I absolutely agree. The problem is that 'superview' is a web view. Otherwise I'd handle it with ease. So it's not that I'm going with a wrong approach, it's that I'm forced to find a hack.

Comment: do you control the content of webview? Is it possible to pass along the touch by writing javascript to intercept a message that you can send it?